# estimating expression

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, integral-inequality

Let $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ where $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.
Prove that
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{12+5z} dz \right| \le \frac{20}{91}\pi.
$$

I tried ML inequality and got this integral $\le \frac{2\pi}{7}$.
$$\left|\frac{1}{12+5z}\right| \le \left|\frac{1}{|12|-|5z|}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{12-5R}\right| = \frac{1}{7}$$
and length of the curve is $2\pi$.

How can I further improve the bound to be $\frac{20}{91}\pi$?

Comment: Instead of $
\int_{\gamma} |\frac{1}{12+5z}| \, dz \le \frac{20}{91}\pi
$ you should write $|
\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{12+5z} \, dz |\le \frac{20}{91}\pi
$

Comment: you are right, sorry for the typo

Comment: It is now unclear whether or not the original question was supposed to discuss $\int|\cdots|$ or $|\int\cdots|$

Comment: I assume that you mean $\int_{\gamma} |\frac{1}{12+5z}| \, |dz|$. – Please clarify!!

Comment: the original question was supposed to discuss | $\int\cdots$ | I also wanted to know how @geetha290krm thought it should be outside?

Comment: @Gary: Re your edit: OP should clarify what they mean, we should not edit the question to what we *guess* they mean. Your change makes the problem trivial.

Comment: @MartinR Edited it back to the OP's version.

Comment: To OP: $|\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{12+5z}| \, dz$ is a complex number which can not be compared to a real number. The question is if you mean $| \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{12+5z} \, dz |$ (which is trivially zero) or $\int_{\gamma} |\frac{1}{12+5z}| \, |dz|$ (which indeed can be shown to be $\le 20\pi/91$).

Comment: $
\left|\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{12+5z} \right|\, dz$ is not meaningful.

Comment: I get it now and corrected the expression, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy's Theorem the integral is $0$. The only pole, $-\frac {12} 5$,  of the integrand is outside the contour since $|-\frac {12} 5|>1$.

Comment: I have some doubt that this was the *real* task (even if OP says so), in particular since $\int_{\gamma} |\frac{1}{12+5z}| \, |dz| \le 20 \pi/91$ can be shown with a small refinement of the approach in the question.

Comment: if you like you could give me a sketch to that too, it would be good for my learning

Comment: @DivyanshVerma: I do not want to answer something which is not asked. But you can ask a new question about $\int_{\gamma} |\frac{1}{12+5z}| \, |dz| \le 20 \pi/91$, if you want.